# Button inside of a Google maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, button, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm trying to build a website where meteor lovers such as myself get a European map with all the meteor impacts over the last 200 years. When the map is initiated meteor icons will render into the map with the according information inside of a infowindow (after clicking on it).

However, I wanted to make it multi-dimensional so beside the meteor data I also used the Google places API. What it does, inside of the info-windows 3 buttons will appear, one saying 'hotel' one for 'restaurant' and one for 'tourist information', users can pick a radius with a slider and once the button is pressed it will look for the establishment in the given radius around the selected meteor. now my problem is:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: "<b>Meteor</b>:            :" + event.feature.getProperty('name') +
    "<br><b>Mass (gram)</b>:   :" + event.feature.getProperty('mass (g)') +
    "<br><b>Date</b>:          :" + event.feature.getProperty('date') +
    "<br><b>Longitude</b>:     :" + event.feature.getProperty('longitude') +
    "<br><b>Latitude</b>:      :" + event.feature.getProperty('latitude') +
    "<br>---Side information---" +
    "<br><b>ID</b>:            :" + event.feature.getProperty('id') +
    "<br><b>Valid name</b>:    :" + event.feature.getProperty('nametype') +
    "<br><b>Fell or Found</b>: :" + event.feature.getProperty('fall') +
    "<br><b>Rec. class</b>:    :" + event.feature.getProperty('recclass') +
    "<br>---Search for nearby establishments---:    :<br>" +
    '<br><button id="hotel" onclick="createEnvironment(event.feature.getProperty("latitude"), event.feature.getProperty("longitude"), "hotel", slider.value)">Hotels</button>' +
    "<button id='restaurants' onclick=" + createEnvironment(event.feature.getProperty('latitude'), event.feature.getProperty('longitude'), 'restaurants', slider.value) + ">Restaurants</button>" +
    "<button id='touristinfo' onclick=" + createEnvironment(event.feature.getProperty('latitude'), event.feature.getProperty('longitude'), 'tourist information', slider.value) + ">Tourist-info</button>" +

});
infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
infowindow.open(map);
```

'hotel' equals the string that Google will search for on the map.
'slider.value' equals the radius, the other stuff doesn't matter.

Whenever I create these buttons it seems to automatically click them whenever I create them. I thought it had to do with the fact that the function was called outside of the string causing them to be executed while creating the button, but putting them all inside of a string didn't seem to help, as shown in the first button. So can someone tell me how I am able to prevent this? or turning them off individually? It won't matter that they all get triggered as long as you can turn them off.

EDIT
This is what the function is referring to:

```
 function createEnvironment(lat, long, soort, range){
        var building = soort;
        var locatie = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

         var request = {
          location: locatie,
          radius: range,
          type: [soort]
         };

         service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
         service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];
           createMarker(results[i], building);
           }
         }
         }
         function createMarker(place) {
            new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: icon,
            position: place.geometry.location,
            map: map
          });
       }
  }
```

and this function is inside of a initmap function (which builds the map) I can't take it out of this function because it will give me an error.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in the browser console?

Comment: I get javascript errors with the posted code: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` and there are functions used that are not defined.  Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits the issue.  Looks like this might be from inside a click listener on a DataLayer... (`event.feature`).

Comment: in your code  you have no function in onclick .. just couple of value ..

Comment: That error code is from the first example of the three, when I put it all between ' ', I can however upload the app to my firebase website so you can see what is going on, https://webvr-cf85e.firebaseapp.com/ as you can see, when you press a meteor, the markers pop up instantly

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**,  not (just) a link to an esxternal site that exhibits the issue.